# Guava cache generics error

Tags: generics, guava

Magical error appears when trying to create guava cache:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

public class Main {

    private static ConcurrentMap<Long, Object> cache = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .build(new CacheLoader<Long, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object load(Long key) throws Exception {
                    return null;
                }
            }).asMap();

}
```

java compile error:

```
Error:(17, 21) java: C:\JavaWorkspace\untitled\src\...\Main.java:17: incompatible types
found   : java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>
required: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<java.lang.Long,java.lang.Object>
```

guava version is 20.0
java version is 1.6

while using java 1.8 and guava 23.0 - it is OK!

The problem is I have to use only 1.6 java

Comment: extremely magic behavia I've ever seen

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround you can use:

```
private static LoadingCache<Long, Object> cache = CacheBuilder
        .newBuilder()
        .build(new CacheLoader<Long, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object load(Long key) throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        });

private static ConcurrentMap<Long, Object> cacheMap = cache.asMap();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it works on JDK 8 because of [enhancements in type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) which were introduced in [that version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html).

On JDK 6 you get type mismatch:

```
found   : ConcurrentMap<Object, Object>
required: ConcurrentMap<Long, Object>
```

because `cache`'s type cannot be inferred without a type hint.

Comment: It's steel confusing while extracting additional variable getting rid the problem. And there is no simple way to init LoadingCache as map out of the box

Comment: @Xaerxess I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900147/send-record-and-wait-for-its-acknowledgement-to-receive) in which I am using guava and I am not sure whether those operations are working correctly or not so wanted to see if you can help me out.