# Guava cache error with generics

Tags: java, caching, guava, java-6

I'm trying to use Google's Guava cache using Guava v20 with Java 6. I have a similar problem as described at [Guava cache generics error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315760/guava-cache-generics-error)

I'm don't need to get the cache as map however but still, my compilation fails at a problem with generics.

Code:

```
private static final LoadingCache<String, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(1000)
        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .build(
                new CacheLoader<String, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object load(String key) throws SystemException, RemoteException {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
        );
```

Compilation error:

```
incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) K1 exist so that com.google.common.cache.Cache<K1,java.lang.Object> conforms to com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
found   : <K1>com.google.common.cache.Cache<K1,java.lang.Object>
required: com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
             .build(
                   ^
```

Do you have any idea where the problem could be, please? Thank you.

**EDIT**
New error message after suggestion:

```
found : com.google.common.cache.Cache<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> 
required: com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> 
            .<String, Object>build(
                                  ^
```

Comment: I don't have those versions here (that's a really old version of Java), but `.<String, Object>build(` should work to explicitly specify the types, I think.

Comment: Thanks. This solved only part of the issue. Now the problem is that found is Cache<String, Object> and required LoadingCache<String, Object>. However in v20 Guava's CacheBuilder.build(CacheLoader) returns LoadingCache (https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v20.0/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.java)

    found   : com.google.common.cache.Cache<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
    required: com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
                .<String, Object>build(
                                                   ^